# Why is the GUI not working, is the code correct?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jpanel

So Im trying to create 3 panels. The first panel has the layout set (e.g. the radio buttons and next button) I`m now adding two new panels which have different background colors. But when I execute the code I get an error of Null point exception. How do I fix that?

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Wizard {

private JLabel lblPicture;
private JRadioButton btLdap, btKerbegos, btSpnego, btSaml2;
private JButton btNext;
private JPanel panel;
private JPanel panelFirst;
private JPanel panelSecond;
CardLayout c1 = new CardLayout();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Wizard();
    }

    public Wizard() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Wizard");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600,360);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        MyPanel();
        RadioButtons();
        Button();
        Image();
        groupButton();
        panel.setLayout(c1);
        panelFirst.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        panelSecond.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        panel.add(panelFirst,"1");
        panel.add(panelSecond,"2");
        c1.show(panel,"panel");
        frame.add(panel); 
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void MyPanel() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
    }

    public void RadioButtons() {
        btLdap = new JRadioButton ("Ldap");
        btLdap.setBounds(60,85,100,20);
        panel.add(btLdap);

        btKerbegos = new JRadioButton ("Kerbegos");
        btKerbegos.setBounds(60,115,100,20);
        panel.add(btKerbegos);

        btSpnego =new JRadioButton("Spnego");
        btSpnego.setBounds(60,145,100,20);
        panel.add(btSpnego);

        btSaml2 = new JRadioButton("Saml2");
        btSaml2.setBounds(60,175,100,20);
        panel.add(btSaml2);
    }

    public void Button() {
        btNext = new JButton ("Next");
        btNext.setBounds(400,260,100,20);
        panel.add(btNext);
        btNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    c1.show(panel, "2");
                }
            });
    }

    public void Image() {
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("image.jpg");
        lblPicture = new JLabel(image);
        lblPicture.setBounds(200,20, 330, 270);
        panel.add(lblPicture);
    }

    private void groupButton() {

        ButtonGroup bg1 = new ButtonGroup( );

        bg1.add(btLdap);
        bg1.add(btKerbegos);
        bg1.add(btSpnego);
        bg1.add(btSaml2);

    }

}
```

Comment: tell us where the null pointer exception happens. Which line. Edit your question to have the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: "*I get an error of Null point exception*" ==> post the stack trace, which contains the exact line on which the exception arose...

Comment: These two lines would throw a NPE: `panelFirst.setBackground(Color.BLUE); panelSecond.setBackground(Color.GREEN);` because none of those panels have been instantiated...

Comment: It is always a good idea to post your stacktrace of the exception.

Answer (score 4):

When I go to run your code I get the null pointer exception you mentioned:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Wizard.<init>(Wizard.java:35)
    at Wizard.main(Wizard.java:20)
```

So, I looked up the line that produced it, in the constructor for Wizard:

```
panelFirst.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```

I see you are setting a property on panelFirst, which is an instance data member of the Wizard class.

I don't see anywhere where you declared `panelFirst = new JPanel();`, which is what created your NullPointerException. It also looks like you haven't initialized many of the other variables as well (for instance, `panel` is the only JPanel I see that has been initialized).

Please look up the constructors for JPanel in the Java API and see how you want to create them for your app. You may also consider using an IDE to generate the GUI code for you.

JPanel API (as of jdk 1.7): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`panelFirst` and `panelSecond` objects are never created.

Answer (score 2):

`panelFirst` and `panelSecond` variable is null it is not declared.

before setting background of panel you need to create it:

```
panelFirst= new JPanel();
```

same thing with panelSecond:

```
panelSecond = new JPanel();
```

When you have a null pointer exception (also known as NPE): you should try to find an `uninitialized variable`. When a variable is declared but not initialized its pointer is pointing to null (i.e it is a null pointer!)